# How do i set an exception in xslt for a special element for CDATA

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

here is the thing. I have a Viewer which can read XML and also html. Now what I want to achieve is the following. I want to have text from a `<note>` transformed to CDATA (check), but if in the `<note>` a specific element is used, *let's call the element `<html>`, all text in that element should not be transformed to CDATA.

Is this even possible? I tried already different things but did not found a solution yet which helped me with my case.

**The input data is this:**

```
<infobox>
 <title>HTML TEST</title>
   <note><b>XML in the Note</b><html html="yes">&lt;h1&gt;Headline&lt;/h1&gt;
         &lt;h2 style="color:green"&gt; Grüne Schrift &lt;/h2&gt;
         &lt;h3 style="color:black"&gt; Schwarze Schrift &lt;/h3&gt;
         &lt;h4 style="color:#FF0000"&gt; Rote Schrift &lt;/h4&gt;</html>
   </note>
</infobox>
```

**My XSL part for the note is this:**

```
    <xsl:template match="note[not(ancestor::info) and not(ancestor::item-content) and not(ancestor::context)]">
      <note type="{@type}">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <div class="{$noteClass}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
      </note>
    </xsl:template>
```

**My published outcome is this:**

```
      <infobox>
        <title id="CAP0e6ba25c-a8a1-45fb-a957-43c3195f9c326">HTML TEST</title>
        <note type=""><![CDATA[<div class="NoteContent">
                  <b>XML in the Note</b>
                  <html>&lt;<div class="html-content">&lt;h1&gt;Headline&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;h2 style="color:green"&gt; Grüne Schrift &lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h3 style="color:black"&gt; Schwarze Schrift &lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h4 style="color:#FF0000"&gt; Rote Schrift &lt;/h4&gt;</div>]]&gt;</html>
               </div>]]></note>
      </infobox>
```

**My wanted published outcome is this:**

```
      <infobox>
        <title id="CAP0e6ba25c-a8a1-45fb-a957-43c3195f9c326">HTML TEST</title>
        <note type=""><![CDATA[<div class="NoteContent">
                  <b>XML in the Note</b></div>]]><html>&lt;h1&gt;Headline&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;h2 style="color:green"&gt; Grüne Schrift &lt;/h2&gt; &lt;h3 style="color:black"&gt; Schwarze Schrift &lt;/h3&gt; &lt;h4 style="color:#FF0000"&gt; Rote Schrift &lt;/h4&gt;</html>

        </note>
      </infobox>
```

So you see, the `<html>` element should be left out of the transformation.

I am open for any suggestion for editing the shown xsl part or for any additional xsl input.

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you need a CDATA section? Or just the escaping of that content? Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use?

Comment: I do need the CDATA section. Only the content from html element should be forwarded as is. must be ver. 2.0

Comment: Which version of which XSLT 2 processor do you use? Does it have an extension function to serialize nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting non `html` elements and wrapping them in a `div` that is serialized is easily possible in XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="note/*[not(self::html)]">
      <xsl:variable name="div-wrapper" as="element(div)">
          <div class="note">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </div>          
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="serialize($div-wrapper)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfA

Creating the CDATA sections could be delegated to `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="note"/>`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfA/1, but as you can see there it is harder to control what happens with white space only content inside of a `note`, in your sample you will get a CDATA section with white space after the `html` element.

Comment: Dear Martin Honnen, thank you very much. Your answere helped me a lot and it works just perfectly. My result is as wanted. All content around the `html` will be published to CDATA and the `html` it self will be forwarded 1:1.